# How can i correct an error in a manual page?

Tags: c, manpage

I think, i might have found an error in a manual page and wanted to know for future reference how i can fix them. In this case it's about the "man 3 getopt".
There is brought up the following example:

```
   getopt()
   The following trivial example program uses getopt() to handle two program options: -n, with
   no associated value; and -t val, which expects an associated value.

   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int flags, opt;
       int nsecs, tfnd;

       nsecs = 0;
       tfnd = 0;
       flags = 0;
       while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "nt:")) != -1) {
           switch (opt) {
           case 'n':
               flags = 1;
               break;
           case 't':
               nsecs = atoi(optarg);
               tfnd = 1;
               break;
           default: /* '?' */
               fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-t nsecs] [-n] name\n",
                       argv[0]);
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
       }

       printf("flags=%d; tfnd=%d; nsecs=%d; optind=%d\n",
               flags, tfnd, nsecs, optind);

       if (optind >= argc) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument after options\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       printf("name argument = %s\n", argv[optind]);

       /* Other code omitted */

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

after the loop there is missing a statement like "optind--;"
otherwise - in my opinion - there is no way to execute this program without getting an error message.

Comment: Did you read the `BUGS` section? Can you contact Frodo Looijaard (`frodo@frodo.looijaard.name`)?

Comment: yeah i read the bugs section, but i just realized that i misunderstood the example. It is meant to take an additional "name" argument which is printed at the end. I was thinking, that the intention was, to print out the option-argument of -t.

Comment: But thanks for the author information. Didn't know, that man pages have this kind of information

Comment: Are you sure? Above program works fine on my box...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not correspond with a real problem.